# c# DataTable.Select: problem with '-' character

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a problem in a C# project. I am using the Select method with a DataTable object.
If I put a '-' in the search string I select nothing.
So here is a code sample of what I have:

```
DataTable table;
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("[Radio Name] LIKE '*Lounge-MP3-96*'");
```

But there is a column with:
Radio Name = 1.FM - The Chillout Lounge-MP3-96

Have I to escape characters? How?

I've just tried

```
DataTable table;
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("[Radio Name] LIKE '*Lounge*'");
```

It works!
So it seems really related to the "-"....

Comment: You've accepted my answer, but you also said you think the hyphens are the problem still.  Is your problem solved?

Comment: I've check the code better and seems that the problem is related to the spaces not to '-'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's the "-".  I thought wildcards needed to be percent symbols for the datatable select (it mimics SQL): "%"?

Try this:

```
DataTable table = GetTableFromSomewhere();
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("[Radio Name] LIKE '%Lounge-MP3-96%'");
```

Also, your example doesn't populate the table with anything in the first place so it wouldn't work - I'm assuming you *do* populate your table somehow.

Comment: In fact it works with both of them... i've just test it and it works